# Python : Unable to return correct count when searching counter with variable as key

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

i'm using a regex to find the strings corresponding to the keys of a counter and  i'm trying to access this counter with a variable that contains one of those strings. It is identical to the key but when i use the variable instead of a key directly, the count returns an *integer* equal to zero. For example, the variable `ngram_b` contains the string `('long,')` which is a key in my counter. With the code below, proba_b will be equal to zero and I get a division by zero error, but `proba_b = probas.ngrams[order][('long,')]` returns the correct answer `0.006.`

```
for ngram, count in joint_probas.items():
    ngram_b = re.search(r'(?<=\), ).*\)(?=\))',str(ngram),re.DOTALL)
    ngram_b= ngram_b.group(0)
    order = int(ngram_b.count('\'')/2)
    proba_b = probas.ngrams[order][ngram_b]
    if proba_b == 0 :
        print(ngram_b, order)
    proba_joint = joint_probas[ngram]
    condi_prob[ngram] = proba_joint / proba_b
```

This is really weird to me and there must be something that I don't understand about how dictionaries work, hopefully someone will see what i'm missing.

EDIT : `Joint_probas` is a counter containing joint probabilities of two ngrams, format of the key (for a one-gram with a bi-gram) : `(('word1',), ('word2', 'word3'))`. `Probas` is a counter containing the probability of all ngrams, format is `('word2', 'word3')` for a bigram. I'm trying to look up the single probability of the second term in each entry in `joint_probas` to compute conditional probabilities.

Thank you

Comment: Hard to tell from your example because joint_probas and probas are not defined but if you see the string ('long,') that may be a one-member tuple containing the string rather than a string containing the parens.  You should update your example to one that people can run without guessing about the input data or values of some of the dictionaries.

Comment: `Joint_probas` is a counter containing joint probabilities of two ngrams, format of the key (for a one-gram with a bi-gram) : `(('word1',), ('word2', 'word3'))`. `Probas` is a counter containing the probability of all ngrams, format is `('word2', 'word3')` for a bigram. I'm trying to look up the single probability of the second term in each entry in `joint_probas` to compute conditional probabilities.

Comment: It seems redundant to wrap `'long,'` in parens, since `type(('long,'))` yields `str`. Not a tuple since it doesn't have a trailing comma. It still seems a bit unclear regarding missing input data, since your `Joint_probas` looks like a tuple of tuples, and `Probas` is a single tuple, rather than dictionaries. Can you give us the dictionary structure of `Joint_probas`?

Comment: I think my problem comes from the fact that I assumed keys in dictionaries are simple strings. Could it be that they are still tuples and i'm trying to access a key that is a tuple with an identical string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given the data structure for `probas` so I can only guess that it is something that has a member which is a list of dictionaries, the keys of which are tuples, like this:

```
>>> class Foo:
>>>     ngrams = [ { ('word2', 'word3') : 11 }, { ('word2', 'word3') : 12 }, { ('word2', 'word3') : 13 } ]
>>> probas = Foo()
```

Define a key of type tuple, and a string version of it:

```
>>> key = ('word2','word3')
>>> type(key)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> strKey = str(key)
>>> type(strKey)
<type 'str'>
```

then:

```
>>> probas.ngrams[2][key]
13
>>> probas.ngrams[2][strKey]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "('word2', 'word3')"
```

I suspect this is your problem, because after the regex, ngram_b will be a string, and you're using that to look up a key which is a tuple.  Can't be sure without a complete example though, which by the way would save everyone some time.

Comment: Exactly, I pretty new to python dictionaries and I assumed keys were simple string representation of what used to be a tuple, that is why I was making my life hard trying to extract the ngrams with a regex while I could do a simple ngram_b[1] because the key is still a tuple. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please upvode or choose any comments or answers that were helpful.  Also next time post a full self-contained code sample.